# How do I return a number of random numbers from this string?

Tags: java, android, random

I have converted my string, `just_numbers`, to an array format with:

```
System.out.println("just_numbers" + Arrays.toString(just_numbers));
```

It looks like `[28, 27, 49, 25, 2, 23, 48, 18, 57, 58, 60, 20]`

How can I select 3 random numbers from the above? The order isn't important.

Right now I am trying with:

```
            Random random = new Random();

            //make random numbers
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
            int number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);

            while (number1 != number2 && number1 != number3) {
              number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
              number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);

            }

            System.out.println("random numbers are :" + number1 + " " + number2  + " " + number3);
```

But I am still getting things like:

```
            random numbers are : 25 25 58
```

That is - duplicates, where each number shoud be listed just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Integer[] getThreeRandomNumber() {
    HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>(3);
    Random random = new Random();
    while (integers.size() < 3) {
   // add number generation logic below
integers.add(Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]));
    }
    return integers.toArray(new Integer[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The outcome is correct according to the code you wrote. 
The problem is on this line

```
while (number1 != number2 && number1 != number3) {
              number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
              number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
}
```

When number one is not equal to two or three, you look for new values,
but instead you should look up new values when number1 **is** equal to number two or three. Also, make it an or statement (a better way to do this would be the following)

```
bool running = true;
while(running){
    running = false; // stop running if the code passes all checks
    if ( a == b || a == c){
       a = Integer.ParseInt(...) //new random number
       running  = true;
    }
    if ( b == c ){
       b = Integer.ParseInt(...) // new random number
       running = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> arrayIntegers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(28, 27, 49, 25, 2, 23, 48, 18, 57, 58, 60, 20));
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    while (numbers.size() < 3) {
        int random = randomGenerator .nextInt(arrayIntegers.size());
        if (!numbers.contains(arrayIntegers.get(random))) {
            numbers.add(arrayIntegers.get(random));
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" random numbers "+numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the condition in the `while` loop it can't do what you expect. Let's interpret the loop literally: *As long as the first number is different to the second one and the it is also different to the third, pick another random number for number2 and number3*

Instructions inside the loop will be executed until the first number is equal to the second because the condition `number1!=number2` will be `false`.

And remember number1 can be different from number2 and number3 but that does not prevent number2 to be equal to number3. There is no condition there to verify that.

So your loop should be somehow like this:

```java
while (number1 == number2 || number1 == number3||number2 == number3) {
if(number1 == number2){
              number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
              }
              if(number1 == number3)
              {
              number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
              }

              if(number2 == number3)
              {
              number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the condition of the while, because you have to compute new numbers if:

- n1 is equal to n2 OR
- n1 is equal to n3 OR
- n2 is equal to n3 OR

So you should use something like

`while ((number1 == number2) || (number1 == number3) || (number3 == number2))`

Here the full code as similar as possible to your question:

```
String[] just_numbers = {"28", "27", "49", "25", "2", "23", "48", "18", "57", "58", "60", "20"};
    Random random = new Random();

        //make random numbers
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
        int number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);

        while ((number1 == number2) || (number1 == number3) || (number3 == number2)) {
          number2 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);
          number3 = Integer.parseInt(just_numbers[random.nextInt(just_numbers.length)]);

        }

        System.out.println("random numbers are :" + number1 + " " + number2  + " " + number3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr  = {28, 27, 49, 25, 2, 23, 48, 18, 57, 58, 60, 20};
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer>  used = new ArrayList();
        used.add(random.nextInt(arr.length));

        while (true && used.size() <= 3){
            int temp = random.nextInt(arr.length);
            if(!used.contains(temp)){
                used.add(temp);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arr[used.get(0)] + " " + arr[used.get(1)] + " " + arr[used.get(2)] + " ");
```